# Reboot hang on "Adding 4051964K swap on /dev/sda5. Priority:-1 extents:1 across 4051964K FS"

Tags: swap

my Ubuntu12.04.5 server edition. DO warmboot that hang on "Adding 4051964K swap on /dev/sda5. Priority:-1 extents:1 across 4051964K FS". What happen of my computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're seeing is probably related to the video. Recent kernels enable by default, the KMS (Kernel Mode Setting)...

Try to add "nomodeset" to you Linux boot option (at GRUB), to disable KMS.

Cheers!